# $m[f;[a, b]] \int^b_a g ≤\int^b_a fg ≤ M[f;[a, b]] \int^b_a g$

Tags: real-analysis

Say that f and g are two continuous real-valued functions on an interval [a, b] whose values are all strictly positive.

I'm trying to figure out why
$$m[f;[a, b]] \int^b_a g ≤\int^b_a fg ≤ M[f;[a, b]] \int^b_a g$$ in this case.

I know $m[f;I]$ is $inf\{f(x): x \in I\}$ and $M[f:I]$ is $sup\{f(x): x\in I\}$ where I is the interval $[a,b]$

I suppose we know that these continuous functions must be integrable on this interval by definition.

I think there must be a theorem that I'm missing that better explains this.

Does anyone have thoughts on a proof?

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of the Darboux integral. Set up the integral for $fg$, then bound $f$ from below and above accordingly.

Comment: Can you see that $m[f;[a, b]] \cdot g(x) \le f(x) \cdot g(x) \le M[f;[a, b]] \cdot g(x)$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that for $f\leq g$ it holds that $\int_a^b f(x)dx \leq \int_a^b g(x)dx$ and that for some constant $c$ it holds that $\int_a^b cf(x)dx = c\int_a^b f(x)dx$.